# Batch rename file with exclamation mark based on folder's name

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder with photos that has more sub-folders which have dates as name.
For instance it is something like `C:\Users\Lorem\Desktop\Photos\22-Dec-98\`.
And inside each date folder I have photos that have short descriptions, e.g `Third morning on site.png`, but some may contain exclamation marks (!).

I managed, by looking at other questions, to come up with a program that adds the date in front of each short description, e.g. `18-Jun-98-Weekend campfire.png`, which is what I wanted, but it fails to do so when the short description has an exclamation mark.

```
@echo OFF

SET /P folderPath="Enter full path of the folder which has the files you want to rename: "
PAUSE
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
PAUSE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b %folderPath%') DO (call :subroutine "%%G") 
PAUSE

:subroutine
 set date=%1
 set date=%date:~1,-1%
 set newPath=%folderPath%\%date%\
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /b %folderPath%\%1\') DO (call :rename "%%F")

:rename
 set fileName=%1
 set fileName=%fileName:~1,-1%
 set name=%date%-%fileName%
 set noname=%newPath%%date%
 REN "%noname%" "%name%"
```

I know the approach that requires input of the folder location is probably not the best option but it was the best workaround I could come up with. All in all, what should I change in/add to my code for it to rename files that contain exclamation marks as well? I would highly appreciate explanations to any changes, if possible, since I am not all that knowledgeable about batch scripting; I only adapted code from different questions/answers. Also I really fail to completely understand what `%1` and `%%F` mean or hold as values so any link to tutorials/short explanation are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On first sight you'll have to separate the subroutines from program flow by a `goto :Eof` .

Comment: As you invoke `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` the exclamation marks have a special meaning to enclose the variables. As you don't use this remove the `EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: The thing is you have got delayed expansion enabled, which consumes the exclamation marks; to work around that issue, you must toggle delayed expansion off and on and enable it only where you actually need it; when you expand a variable normally like `%fileName%`, for example, or when you expand a `for` variable reference like `%%F` or an argument reference like `%1`, make sure delayed expansion is disabled; actually I cannot see why you enabled it at all...